# JQuery Masked Input plugin not working for an area code

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I'm working with JQuery Masked Input plugin. I have a mask for an area code which simply inserts parenthesis at the beginning and at the end of 3 digits like: (123). When my area code input field has a 3 digit value, the plugin inserts the left parenthesis but not the right one. I would expect it to insert both parenthesis or none of them. If you type anything in the textbox, it automatically fills the right parenthesis. Here is an example:

```js
$(function(){
 
  $('#areacode').mask('(000)', { placeholder: '(___)'});



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="areacode"  value = "123"/>
```

Could anybody let me know the source of this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working for me. If I input 3 numbers, it adds the right parenthesis as well.

Comment: I think you want to remove the value from the input and add it to the placeholder maybe.

Comment: @ItsGreg : It works if you enter three numbers. However, it does not work when you are displaying data.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can fix it. It is not constructive to downvote without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I've sort of found a solution. It's not pretty, but triggering the `keyup` event seems to fix it.

```js
$(function(){
 
  $('#areacode').mask('(000)', { placeholder: '(___)'}).trigger('keyup');



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="areacode"  value = "123"/>
```